# extracting hashtags out of Twitter trending topics data with Python Tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, hashtag, tweepy, trending

I'm having a following problem:

using the Twitter API and tweepy module, I want to monitor the trending topics and extract hashtags out of the data.

This code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import tweepy, json

CONSUMER_KEY = 'key'
CONSUMER_SECRET = 'secret'
ACCESS_KEY = 'key'
ACCESS_SECRET = 'secret'
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_KEY, ACCESS_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

trends1 = api.trends_place(1)
print trends1
```

gives me data about globally trending topics that is structured like this:

```
[{u'created_at': u'2014-04-16T12:13:15Z', u'trends': [{u'url': u'http://twitter.com/search?q=%22South+Korea%22', u'query': u'%22South+Korea%22', u'name': u'South Korea', u'promoted_content': None}, {u'url': u'http://twitter.com/search?q=%23FETUSONEDIRECTIONDAY', u'query': u'%23FETUSONEDIRECTIONDAY', u'name': u'#FETUSONEDIRECTIONDAY', u'promoted_content': None}, {u'url': u'http://twitter.com/search?q=%23PrayForSouthKorea', u'query': u'%23PrayForSouthKorea', u'name': u'#PrayForSouthKorea', u'promoted_content': None}, {u'url': u'http://twitter.com/search?q=%23GaraGaraRP', u'query': u'%23GaraGaraRP', u'name': u'#GaraGaraRP', u'promoted_content': None}, {u'url': u'http://twitter.com/search?q=%23%D8%A5%D8%B3%D9%85_%D8%A3%D9%85%D9%8A_%D8%A8%D8%AC%D9%88%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%8A', u'query': u'%23%D8%A5%D8%B3%D9%85_%D8%A3%D9%85%D9%8A_%D8%A8%D8%AC%D9%88%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%8A', u'name': u'#\u0625\u0633\u0645_\u0623\u0645\u064a_\u0628\u062c\u0648\u0627\u0644\u064a', u'promoted_content': None}, {u'url': u'http://twitter.com/search?q=%23Kad%C4%B1nlarKamyon%C5%9Eof%C3%B6r%C3%BCOlursa', u'query': u'%23Kad%C4%B1nlarKamyon%C5%9Eof%C3%B6r%C3%BCOlursa', u'name': u'#Kad\u0131nlarKamyon\u015eof\xf6r\xfcOlursa', u'promoted_content': None}, {u'url': u'http://twitter.com/search?q=%22Dear+My+BestFriend%22', u'query': u'%22Dear+My+BestFriend%22', u'name': u'Dear My BestFriend', u'promoted_content': None}, {u'url': u'http://twitter.com/search?q=%22%D0%A1%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0+100%22', u'query': u'%22%D0%A1%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0+100%22', u'name': u'\u0421\u0430\u043c\u043e\u043e\u0431\u043e\u0440\u043e\u043d\u0430 100', u'promoted_content': None}, {u'url': u'http://twitter.com/search?q=%22If+I+Stay%22', u'query': u'%22If+I+Stay%22', u'name': u'If I Stay', u'promoted_content': None}, {u'url': u'http://twitter.com/search?q=Gabashvili', u'query': u'Gabashvili', u'name': u'Gabashvili', u'promoted_content': None}], u'as_of': u'2014-04-16T12:20:29Z', u'locations': [{u'woeid': 1, u'name': u'Worldwide'}]}]
```

Is this a python list, containing several dictionaries? How can I extract hashtags out of that data and save them into new variables?

I'm new to python so please explain your choices.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example you have a single entry in your list, consisting of nested dicts with key value 'trends' each value is a another dict, the one you are interested in is 'name' and in particular if it starts with '#':

```
In [180]:

[x for x in temp[0]['trends'] if x['name'].find('#') ==0]
Out[180]:
[{'name': '#FETUSONEDIRECTIONDAY',
  'promoted_content': None,
  'query': '%23FETUSONEDIRECTIONDAY',
  'url': 'http://twitter.com/search?q=%23FETUSONEDIRECTIONDAY'},
 {'name': '#PrayForSouthKorea',
  'promoted_content': None,
  'query': '%23PrayForSouthKorea',
  'url': 'http://twitter.com/search?q=%23PrayForSouthKorea'},
 {'name': '#GaraGaraRP',
  'promoted_content': None,
  'query': '%23GaraGaraRP',
  'url': 'http://twitter.com/search?q=%23GaraGaraRP'},
 {'name': '#إسم_أمي_بجوالي',
  'promoted_content': None,
  'query': '%23%D8%A5%D8%B3%D9%85_%D8%A3%D9%85%D9%8A_%D8%A8%D8%AC%D9%88%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%8A',
  'url': 'http://twitter.com/search?q=%23%D8%A5%D8%B3%D9%85_%D8%A3%D9%85%D9%8A_%D8%A8%D8%AC%D9%88%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%8A'},
 {'name': '#KadınlarKamyonŞoförüOlursa',
  'promoted_content': None,
  'query': '%23Kad%C4%B1nlarKamyon%C5%9Eof%C3%B6r%C3%BCOlursa',
  'url': 'http://twitter.com/search?q=%23Kad%C4%B1nlarKamyon%C5%9Eof%C3%B6r%C3%BCOlursa'}]
```

**EDIT**
To get just the hastags:

```
In [181]:

[x['name'] for x in temp[0]['trends'] if x['name'].find('#') ==0]
Out[181]:
['#FETUSONEDIRECTIONDAY',
 '#PrayForSouthKorea',
 '#GaraGaraRP',
 '#إسم_أمي_بجوالي',
 '#KadınlarKamyonŞoförüOlursa']
```

You can use `startswith` instead of `find`:

```
[x['name'] for x in temp[0]['trends'] if x['name'].startswith('#')]
```

Answer (score 3):

Your data is a list containing one dictionary. One of the keys in this dictionary is called trends. The value for this key is a list of dictionaries. Each of these dictionaries contains a key called name, which holds a string containing a hashtag. Here's an example of accessing your data:

```
hashtags = []
trends = data[0]['trends']
for trend in trends:
    name = trend['name']
    if name.startswith('#'):
        hashtags.append(name)
```

This can be compacted to:

```
hashtags = [trend['name'] for trend in data[0]['trends'] if trend['name'].startswith('#')]
```

First three lines of output:

```
>>> for hashtag in hashtags:
        print(hashtag)
#FETUSONEDIRECTIONDAY
#PrayForSouthKorea
#GaraGaraRP
```

Comment: Both look really nice because they filter 'name' and extract just hashtags!, but I keep getting 'KeyError: 0', any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @loop_digga it means that your data is actually a dictionary, and not a list as you have shown. Try my answer again.

Comment: That's strange, I just copy pasted the data output from ipython notebook. Now the error is: 'TypeError: unhashable type: 'list''.

Comment: @loop_digga well now you have just changed the data from a dictionary back into a list again. Try either `data` or `data[0]`.

Comment: neither works, and I'm not doing anything else that your code doesn't do :s